# What is the difference between an alert and an incident?

Tags: pagerduty

I see both the terms "alert" and "incident" being used on PagerDuty. What are the differences? How are they related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PagerDuty receives a qualifying event (from a monitoring tool, for example), it triggers an alert, which in turn triggers an incident. Multiple alerts can be aggregated into a single incident for triage, which streamlines incident handoff between teams, centralizes critical information, and reduces notification fatigue. Alerts can move from one incident to another, either [manually](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/edit-incidents#move-alerts-to-another-incident) or via an automated process, such as [Alert Grouping](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/event-intelligence#alert-grouping). Here is more information on it: https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/alerts